# How to use the Lua management freeswitch gateway

Tags: lua, gateway, freeswitch

all

```
 I want to manage freeswitch gateway by lua,how to do it?
 such as:


   <configuration name="lua.conf" description="LUA Configuration">
  <settings>

    <param name="xml-handler-script" value="gen_dir_user_xml.lua" />
    <param name="xml-handler-bindings" value="directory" />

  </settings>
</configuration>
```

this is manage the users configuration.
thanks

---

why to add lua code? this question is required config file and any lua code,but it has lua code.. the user management lua code so:

```
local req_domain = params:getHeader("domain")
local req_key    = params:getHeader("key")
local req_user   = params:getHeader("user")
local req_password   = params:getHeader("pass")

local dbh = freeswitch.Dbh("freeswitch","postgres","tttt");
freeswitch.consoleLog("NOTICE","start connect DB...\r\n");
assert(dbh:connected());
dbh:query("select password from users where id="..req_user,function(row)
        freeswitch.consoleLog("NOTICE",string.format("%s\n",row.password))
        req_password=string.format("%s",row.password)
end);
dbh:release();

freeswitch.consoleLog("NOTICE","info:"..req_domain.."--"..req_key.."--"..req_user.."--"..req_password.."\n");



--assert (req_domain and req_key and req_user,
--"This example script only supports generating directory xml for a single user !\n")
if req_domain ~= nil and req_key~=nil and req_user~=nil then
    XML_STRING =
    [[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <document type="freeswitch/xml">
      <section name="directory">
        <domain name="]]..req_domain..[[">
          <params>
        <param name="dial-string"
        value="{presence_id=${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain}}${sofia_contact(${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain})}"/>
          </params>
          <groups>
        <group name="default">
          <users>
            <user id="]] ..req_user..[[">
              <params>
            <param name="password" value="]]..req_password..[["/>
            <param name="vm-password" value="]]..req_password..[["/>
              </params>
              <variables>
            <variable name="toll_allow" value="domestic,international,local"/>
            <variable name="accountcode" value="]] ..req_user..[["/>
            <variable name="user_context" value="default"/>
            <variable name="directory-visible" value="true"/>
            <variable name="directory-exten-visible" value="true"/>
            <variable name="limit_max" value="15"/>
            <variable name="effective_caller_id_name" value="Extension ]] ..req_user..[["/>
            <variable name="effective_caller_id_number" value="]] ..req_user..[["/>
            <variable name="outbound_caller_id_name" value="${outbound_caller_name}"/>
            <variable name="outbound_caller_id_number" value="${outbound_caller_id}"/>
            <variable name="callgroup" value="techsupport"/>
              </variables>
            </user>
          </users>
        </group>
          </groups>
        </domain>
      </section>
    </document>]]
else
    XML_STRING =
    [[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <document type="freeswitch/xml">
      <section name="directory">
      </section>
    </document>]]
end
```

Comment: There is no lua code there

Comment: why to add lua code? this question is required config file and any lua code,but it has lua code.. the user management lua code so:

Answer (score 0):

Look at fusionpbx source code, it has lots of Lua code.